# How to override paste notification for Paste as plain text button?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When users want to paste by clicking "Paste as plain text" button, the next message pops up "Press Ctrl+Shift+V to paste. Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option."

Is any way to override this message for all CKEditor instances?

Answer (score 1):

The new version of CKEditor still has the paste, paste as text, and paste from word buttons in the full menu, but when clicked a nicer looking modal comes up saying to paste using CTRL + V.  You can see a demo here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/basicstyles.html

Even if you download the new version, you will still get a modal if you click one of the paste buttons.

If you want to remove the paste buttons from the menu (and simply tell users to use CTRL + V) and if you want to paste plain (unformatted) text with CTRL + V add this to your config.js file.

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
config.removeButtons = 'Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord';
```